# What is sa_family_t

Tags: c++, sockets, types, identifier

I'm following [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/), and I'm using VC++ 2010, but when I copy paste the structs into my program, some of the types come up as incorrect identifiers. For example:

`u_int32_t` came up as that, and after some searching I found out those are old types from the C language circa 1999. I could have just included *stdint.h*, but that would require me to remember what they meant. Instead I used the standard `int`, which is 32 bits long (4 bytes), and for the other ones which are 64 bits long (8 bytes), I used `long long int`.

Anyways, I'm narrowing down to my last syntax error and it says `sa_family_t` is an invalid indentifier. I don't have a clue what its supposed to be and searching has turned up nothing. That's my problem, I don't know what I should specify for a type identifier for that.

Another thing that's bothering me is this:     `char __ss_pad1[_SS_PAD1SIZE];` The `SS_PAD1SIZE` thing comes up in red as invalid too.

Comment: "I used the standard "int", which is 32 bits long" - not on every platform, that's why uin32_t & co are there.

Comment: Can you post some of your code so that we can see how `sa_family_t` is being used?  Also, beware, `u_int32_t` is an unsigned type while int is signed.  This can cause undesirable behavior in your program later on depending on how the variable declared as int is being used.

Comment: _"those are old types from the C language circa 1999"_ No, they're _new_ types from 1999 -- remember C is over 40 years old, 1999 is not long ago in C terms.

Comment: `u_int32_t` is not a standard type in C or POSIX.  `uint32_t` is a standard (but technically optional) type in C99 and later.  Remember that some C compilers (notably those from Microsoft) have made very little effort to implement C99 yet; they are still basically C89 compilers.

Comment: I just have to comment that you're doing some horrific things. I hope this is only just to learn basic concepts. Which you need to do, since you don't understand why exact integer sizes are a big deal in networking. I also hope that you will never, ever use this frankencode you are creating for anything important or that you care about.

Comment: OrgnlDave, I don't know exactly why using incorrect numbers in networking is bad, but I can guess: too short an IP address could wind up somewhere other than the destination address, am I right? I understand some systems use shorter bit lengths, and numbers have to fit the type. I don't know how anything I am I doing could be "Horrid" because you've never seen my own code, only what I've pasted from Beej's tutorial, and my decision to use normal short,long, etc. int's in place of C defined datatypes! By "Old" I meant "C", the language C++ was based off of (meaning older language, I know they'r

Comment: e both really old, 40 years is a long time). Can I please get an answer as to why I have to typedef? I'm guessing its because its easier to change things later on, if newer code uses the old type. 
Also, what is "_SS_PAD1SIZE"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[sa_family_t should be an unsigned integer.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html)  The Windows header files don't conform to that standard.  Winsock.h defines the sockaddr struct as follows:

```
struct sockaddr {
        u_short sa_family;              /* address family */
        char    sa_data[14];            /* up to 14 bytes of direct address */
};
```

So to compile your code you're going to need to typedef sa_family_t yourself.

Comment: 'yourself'...meaning 'yourself, probably as `typedef u_short sa_family_t`'?

Comment: struct sockaddr_storage {
 sa_family_t  ss_family;     // address family

    // all this is padding, implementation specific, ignore it:
    char      __ss_pad1[_SS_PAD1SIZE];
    long long int   __ss_align;
    char      __ss_pad2[_SS_PAD2SIZE];
};


That's the code.

H2CO3, I knew that, thanks though. What I don't know is if it matters with modern computers. Say I wrote a program with 32 bit ints, on my nearly 2 year old PC, and gave it to a friend whose is 4 years old. Will it work? I don't think 16 bit computers are made or even used these days...

Comment: Sorry, I'm a total novice who doesn't know everything about C++. I do know the "u_" in "u_int32_t" stood for unsigned, but I read something which said modern C++ compilers automatically set the int to unsigned.

Carey Gregory, why must I typedef that? Can't I just rewrite sa_family_t as an unsigned integer?

Lastly, I forgot "circa" meant old, I just meant it was from 1999. 

Thanks guys. ^_^

Comment: No, modern compilers do not make int unsigned.  Without the unsigned keyword, int always means a signed integer.  Yes, you can replace sa_family_t everywhere it occurs with unsigned int if you prefer, but it would be a lot easier and more maintainable to just typedef sa_family_t in one place.

Comment: Oh, and circa means around or about, an approximate date.  It doesn't mean old.

Comment: No, I have no excuse though school started again and I didn't have time to work on my project or check back here. I apologize. I don't understand this site very well. What is an accept, what does an upvote do? I learned later on that I was doing completely the wrong thing with SDL and sockets. For one I've always been fascinated with starting from scratch to learn so I wanted to make a simple GUI with SDL. Then I would incorporate that into my Chat program. SDL is for graphics and I didn't know what I was doing. I thought I had to use the code in Beej's tutorial to use sockets. That was the

Comment: problem with my program. This question was completely stupid of me. I had no idea what I was talking about. I wish this question could be deleted because I don't think it will help anyone.

Comment: You never know who it might help since the Windows typedef doesn't conform to the standard.

Comment: Ok then though I don't see how. Thank you for donating your time to help though.

Comment: Linux also [defines `sa_family_t`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14/source/include/uapi/linux/socket.h#L12) as `unsigned short`. I don't know if it's fair to say the Windows doesn't conform to the spec here. My reading of the spec is that any unsigned integer type is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone arrives at this answer and is looking for `sa_family_t;` under Linux, it is defined here:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1a5304fecee523060f26e2778d9d8e33c0562df3/include/linux/socket.h#L28

```
typedef __kernel_sa_family_t    sa_family_t;
```

In turn, `__kernel_sa_family_t` is defined here:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1a5304fecee523060f26e2778d9d8e33c0562df3/include/uapi/linux/socket.h#L10

```
typedef unsigned short __kernel_sa_family_t;
```

So ultimately, `sa_family_t` is an `unsigned short`, i.e. 2 bytes. This brings the entire `struct sockaddr` to a neat 16 bytes:

```
struct sockaddr {
    sa_family_t sa_family;  // unsigned short
    char        sa_data[14];
```